# Mouse freezes if keyboard is used

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse, freeze

I just setup a new Windows 7 computer and if I use the keyboard, especially the Ctrl/Alt/Shift keys, the mouse freezes. The keyboard is fine (as a matter of fact, my mouse is frozen as I write this...). The only solution is to shutdown and restart the computer (rebooting doesn't get it done). This happens on the login screen as well.

The mouse and keyboard are USB and they are running through an Aten HDMI KVM.

I've updated all the drivers, done all the windows updates, checked BIOS to see if there were any settings (and my fancy BIOS actually has mouse support and it **doesn't** freeze there). No joy.  Any ideas?

UPDATE
I've narrowed it down to the KVM. It is an Aten CubiQ 1794, which has USB 2.0 ports. If I plug the keyboard and mouse directly into the computer, they work. If I use the KVM, the mouse freezes.  The Mobo (Asus Maximus VII Hero) has both USB 3 and 2 ports. I tried both with KVM and both have same issue.  I also tried to change the BIOS EHCI setting and the issue occurs with it is enabled and disabled.  So, this seems to be a USB compatibility issue. Any ideas on how I might solve it?

Comment: What happens if you bypass (don't use) the KVM?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like mouse and keyboard ought to be plugged in to a motherboard USB port.  I don't know much about Aten HDMI KVM, but it seems like it would be a post-boot device, though if your BIOS can find and use them...?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch

Comment: Oh...one of those.  I used to have one (different brand) when I was working, and I never had any problems with keyboard or mouse freezing.  Though as I recall, there were specific USB ports that were specifically pre-boot ports.

Comment: There is a setting in BIOS about USB ports. It is set to be enabled right away, so the keyboard and mouse are useful before the OS been loaded. As I mentioned, I can enter BIOS with the current setup (USB keyboard/mouse through the KVM) with no problems...both work.

Answer (score 0):

Some laptops have a "protection" so that you can use the mouse while using the keyboard this can be disabled in the driver configurations for the mouse.

Comment: It is not a laptop, but a desktop.

Comment: What make is your computer?